# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Hola soy bastante nuevo en PHP y yengo problemas al conectar a una base de datos de Cpanel que me genera el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Usando el código de conexión

```
<?php

class Db{
  private $servername = "localhost";
  private $dbname = "baselogin";
  private $username = "testsite";
  private $password = "1234567";

    private static $conexion=null;
    private function __construct(){}
    public static function conectar(){

    try {
        self::$conexion=new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return self::$conexion;
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
  }
?>
```

Cuando retiro la conexión de la clase Db y retiro las funciones la conexión funciona, pero necesito necesito las funciones. Ya intente cambiar el localhost por la ip y aun no funciona

Comment: Yo un error que veo es: las propiedades que almacenan los valores de conexión son y deberían estar dentro de la clase y no por fuera

Comment: Almacene las propiedades de la conexión dentro de la clase pero el error persiste

Comment: Es que eso solo era parte de las observaciones y no la solución general en si, checa lo que A.Cedano te aportó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas en tu código, las voy a enumerar aquí y luego te propongo una solución:

1. Las credenciales de conexión no están dentro de la clase, por lo tanto no las está reconociendo. Tienes que declararlas dentro del cuerpo de la clase (preferiblemente como `private`)  y luego en `conectar()` invocarlas usando `$this`. En la respuesta yo he creado una variable `$dsn` para poner ahí las credenciales, incluyendo además una configuración para el charset, que te ahorrará problemas si tuvieras que trabajar con datos acentuados o con caracteres especiales.
2. Esta es una mejora que me permito sugerirte: evita usar `setAttributes` una vez creada la conexión. En PDO puedes pasar un cuarto parámetro con los atributos. Eso evita tener que modificar de nuevo el objeto una vez creado. Por eso he puesto un array `$mOptions` con los atributos. Ahí me he permitido agregar un atributo importante que apaga las preparaciones emuladas. [En mi respuesta sobre *Inyección SQL*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967) he tratado largamente esa aspecto, demostrando que se puede inyectar código cuando las preparaciones emuladas están en `TRUE`, configuración que PDO trae por defecto, por tanto, conviene apagarlas con `FALSE`
3. Tenías declarado el constructor de la clase como `private`. Es raro que lo hayas puesto así. No podrás crear instancias de la clase desde fuera de ella.
4. Tenías declarado el método `contectar()`  como `static`. No podrás invocarlo desde contextos no estáticos.
5. Finalmente, me he permitido sugerirte que no muestres mensajes de error internos con `getMessage()`, porque podría revelar datos interesantes para los hackers. Por ejemplo, PDO tiene el defecto de que cuando falla ¡revela la contraseña en el mensaje de error! Es algo realmente absurdo y no sé por qué han hecho eso, así que no deberías mostrar mensajes con `getMessage`, ni escribirlos en el log de errores y como consejo usa contraseñas largas, de 30 o más caracteres, porque así quedaría truncada en caso de mostrarse o escribirse en un log de errores.

Eso es todo. Intenta de este modo, debería funcionar:

```
<?php
    class Db{
        private static $conexion=null;
        private $servername = "localhost";
        private $dbname = "baselogin";
        private $username = "testsite";
        private $password = "1234567";
    
        private function __construct(){}
        public  function conectar(){
    
        try {
            $dsn="mysql:host={$this->servername};dbname=$this->dbname;charset=UTF8";
            $mOptions=array(
                              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                              PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
    
                            )
            self::$conexion=new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $mOptions);
            return self::$conexion;
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo "Connection failed: ERROR PERSONALIZADO EVITA USAR getMessage";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, muchas gracias por el tiempo y las observaciones que me aportaste. Implemente la solución que me diste pero el error persiste. Realice la conexión con MySQLi en vez de PDO para probar y funciono, pero no se como por MySQLi poder usar las funciones _construct() y conectar()

Comment: @alec_ Solo tienes que modificar la clase, poniendo dentro de ella los métodos propios de `MySQLi` en lugar de los métodos de `PDO`.

Comment: @A.Cedano **Aporta mucho valor** el comentario de PDO con `getMessage` y también el de las contraseñas de mas de 30 caracteres. Yo particularmente no lo sabía. Gracias

Comment: @Liyo me alegro de que te haya sido útil. Un saludo.