# ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

//Estoy usando php, mysql y xampp se usar mysql y php pero cuando quiero conectarlos no puedo

```
<?php

    class Conexion{
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $user = "root";
        private $password = "";
        private $db = "db_sistema";
        private $conect;

        public function __construct(){
            $connectionString = "mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db.";charset=utf8";
            try{
                $this->conect = new PDO($connectionString,$this->user,$this->password);

                $this->conect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (Exception $e){
                $this->conect ='Error de conexion';
                echo "ERROR: ". $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    $conect = new Conexion();
?>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error: SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/343069/error-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-localhost-using-passw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema puede ser porque no envias password al intentar conectarte. Revisa si tu servidor mysql tiene desactivada dicha opción. Se recomienda que siempre la bd no este publicada en internet y/o se limite que ips deben poder conectarse desde fuera del servidor.