# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied

Tags: base-de-datos, pdo, xampp

tengo este codigo para una conexion de base de datos con PDO, y me da el siguiente eror: ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Aqui os dejo el codigo:

```
<?php
    class Conexion{
        private static $conexion;

        public static function abrir_conexion(){
            if(!isset(self::$conexion)){
                try{
                    include_once "config.inc.php";
/*
                    $dsn="mysql:host={$this->nombre_servidor};dbname=$this->nombre_base_datos;charset=UTF8";
                    $mOptions=array(
                              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                              PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 

                            )
                    self::$conexion=new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $mOptions);
                    */
                    self::$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$nombre_servidor; dbname=$nombre_base_datos", $nombre_usuario, $password);
                    self::$conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    self::$conexion -> exec("SET CHARACTER utf8");

                    print "abierta";
                }catch(PDOException $ex){
                    print "ERROR: " . $ex -> getMessage() . "<br>";
                    die();
                }
            }
        }

        public static function cerrar_conexion(){
            if (isset(self::$conexion)){
                self::$conexion = null;
                print "cerrada";
            }
        }

        // Para usar referencia a conexion fuera de esta clase ya que es privada
        public static function obtener_conexion(){
            return self::$conexion;
        }
    }

?>
```

Config.inc.php:

```
<?php
    // $config= array("nombre_servidor" => "localhost","nombre_usuario" => "root","password" => "","nombre_base_datos" => "blog");
    $nombre_servidor = "localhost";
    $nombre_usuario = "root";
    $password = "";
    $nombre_base_datos = "blog";
?>
```

Lo que tengo comentado a mitad de codigo es otra prueba que he hecho utilizando este enlaze([Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/343069/error-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-localhost-using-passw)) pero sigue sin funcionarme, y nose como utilizar mysqli.

Aqui los usuarios de base de datos:
[[image: 1]]

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que el usuario y contraseña son correctos?

Comment: Haz un `printf("%s\n%s\n%s","mysql:host=$nombre_servidor; dbname=$nombre_base_datos",$nombre_usuario, $password);` y verifica que todo es correcto. Verifica también que `$nombre_base_datos` es la BD correcta, pues puede haber más de una BD. A veces ayuda poner el puerto en el DSN, suele ser el `3306`, pero puede ser otro: `port=3306`

Comment: Me aparece lo siguiente, son correctos. mysql:host=localhost; dbname=blog root.

El puerto estoy usando el 3307 en mysql y lo he cambiado en los sitios correspondientes.

Comment: Intenta agregar el puerto al DSN de este modo: `"mysql:host=$nombre_servidor;dbname=$nombre_base_datos;port=3307"` si no funciona, prueba con la IP en lugar de localhost: `"mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=$nombre_base_datos"`

Comment: Estableciendo el puerto hemos cambiado de error a este,¿ le tengo que meter el meta charset="UTF-8" ?:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'utf8' at line 1.

Comment: A ver, esto sobra: `self::$conexion -> exec("SET CHARACTER utf8");`, basta con poner el charset en el DSN. Dime cómo tienes el DSN, cada valor debe estar separado por `;` y es mejor que no dejes espacios en blanco entre valores.

Comment: El DSN debe quedar así: `"mysql:host=elHost;dbname=laBaseDeDatos;charset=elCharset;port=elPuerto"` cambiando cada cosa después de `=` por la variable o valor correcto. La conexión ahora debería estar funcionando y el Sintax error es porque la consulta que intentas para el charset es errónea realmente.

Comment: Vale solucionado, el error era el self conexion del character utf8, y que debia de establecer el puerto, el dejar espacios entre valores no afecta y no hace falta que ponga el charset. Muchas gracias

Comment: El charset lo debes poner si quieres `utf8`, de lo contrario podrías tener problemas en valores acentuados, pero es mejor ponerlo en DSN como te indiqué en mi comentario. En la otra pregunta que enlazas en la pregunta me parece haber respondido que no es conveniente molestar a la conexión una vez creada, ni para configurar el charset mediante una consulta SQL (que era lo que fallaba en tu caso porque esa consulta era errónea), ni para setear las opciones, pues PDO admite un cuarto parámetro para ello, que le puedes pasar en forma de array al constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez corregido el DSN, agregando el puerto, necesario en algunos casos, conviene decir que el charset lo debes poner si quieres `utf8`, de lo contrario podrías tener problemas en valores acentuados, pero es mejor ponerlo en DSN.

Por otra parte, no es conveniente molestar a la conexión una vez creada, ni para configurar el charset mediante una consulta SQL (que era el segundo fallo en tu caso porque esa consulta era errónea), ni para setear las opciones, pues PDO admite un cuarto parámetro para ello, que le puedes pasar en forma de array al constructor.

También, apagar las preparaciones emuladas es un asunto de seguridad, no deberías ignorarlo.

De hecho, renunciaste a esas buenas prácticas, como se puede ver en el bloque comentado de tu código...

Otra cosa, es más seguro usar la IP como puerto, que usar el nombre.

Por tanto, tu código puede quedar escrito de esta manera:

```
$mOptions=array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
)
self::$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$nombre_servidor;dbname=$nombre_base_datos;port=3307;charset=utf8", $nombre_usuario, $password, $mOptions);
/*
   A partir de aquí nada más con respecto a la conexión
  la misma ya está totalmente configurada, 
  ahora sólo úsala, 
  no la molestes más con otras configuraciones
*/
```